# Working in Pandas Error: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am using NHL player stats and I want to predict the total points a player will get in the next season given their previous season stats. I am trying to create a column on the dataframe called "Next_Year_Points" but I keep receiving the same error: *index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0*. My relevant dataframe columns are 'Player', 'Season', and 'PTS'.

```
def GetPTS(player, year):
    next_year_row = X_train[(X_train['Player'] == player) & (X_train['Season'] == year+1)]
    next_year_pts = next_year_row['PTS'].values[0]
    return next_year_pts

Next_Year_Points = []
for index, row in X_train.iterrows():
    nxt_yr_pts.append(GetPTS(row['Player'], row['Season']))
```

When I use my custom function on its own it works ie. GetPTS('Sidney Crosby', 2017) will return his 2018 points. However, when I loop through the dataframe to create a list of next year's points I get the error.

Apologies if my formatting is terrible or I am missing information, this is my first post.

TIA

Comment: A little difficult to debug without more code, but could it be that X_train['Season'] == year+1 doesn't exist for certain players?

Comment: Line 5 you initialise an array `Next_Year_Points`, but line 7 you append to an array called `nxt_yr_pts` - is this just a typo in this post or in your own code too?

Comment: @RyoheiNamiki you got it, thank-you!!!